# Opening a different form inside running form without interrupting execution of the !st form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a windows form application which is supposed to do multiple tasks on a system like taking snapshot of the desktop, finding free disk space, popping up a message, creating file and so on..

My question here is, since I have multiple tasks and one of which is popping up of a message, I am wondering how I can achieve that without interrupting execution of other tasks. i.e I have for loop in which all the tasks are executed one by one, when it comes to message task it waits for the message box to close, and does not proceed to the next task until and unless  Messagebox is closed.

Here is code snippet:

```
foreach (string str in Processqueue)
{
    switch (str)
    {
        case "DISKSPACE": DiskSpace();
            break;

        case "MESSAGE": Message();
            break;

        case "SCREENSHOT": Screenshot();
            break;

    }
}
```

Here Processqueue is string array.

Did some research and it seems like I need to use different thread for that. I am new to the Winform, can anyone please help.

I do not need to open a new form inside the existing one. I need to open the new form(for message task only) and in the background do other remaining tasks on main form.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly but before diving into multithreading you may take a look (if you already haven't) at `Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Windows Forms`. In general, this allows you to have one `parent form` and many `child forms` and maybe you could use different `child form` for each task you want to perform. Not sure if this gonna be helpful for you but I think it might help if you take a quick look.

Comment: Okay, I will take a look at MDI.

Comment: I don't think that MDI will help much unless the child windows do NOT share the same UI thread.

Comment: Just to clarify I do not have multiple forms for each of the task. Its only for Message task I need either a separate form or a just a message box which will not interrupt other tasks.

Comment: Off-topic: **1.** I know you didn't ask for it, but may I humbly do a tiny code review here? I suggest that you replace this whole `switch` block with proper polymorphism: i.e. define something like an `Run` method on your `ProcessQueue` class, and just do a `foreach (var process in processQueue) { process.Run(); }` **2.** Consider renaming `ProcessQueue` to `Process`. `foreach (ProcessQueue process in processQueue)` sounds unlogical IMHO: Why is the type called `ProcessQueue`, but the variable `process`? And why can you iterate over a `processQueue` and retrieve `ProcessQueue` objects again?

Comment: I have just put piece of code which is relevant to my question. I will modify my question to sound logical.

Answer (score 2):

One very simple solution is to display your forms modeless instead of modally. That is, instead of calling `form.ShowDialog()`, call `form.Show()`.

This solution implies, however, that you cannot use `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(…)`, since these message boxes are always modal. You would have to create your own message box form that looks like `MessageBox` (but can be shown modeless, like other `Form`s).

Another solution is indeed to created a separate STA thread for each form, and call `Application.Run(form);` on that thread. You get better separation — that is, only forms on the same thread can block one another, and if each form gets a separate thread, blocking is very unlikely to occur. The major disadvantage (next to lots of probably unnecessary threads) is that it's going to be somewhat trickier if your forms need to interact.

Comment: At the OP: Just use the first method (`form.Show()`); don't start with different threads, it's much more trouble than it's worth, certainly if you don't understand the finer points of multithreading.

Comment: hi @stakx, your solution worked fine untill I used timer to do all the tasks. please refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951542/how-to-automate-task-of-consuming-webservice) DO I need to use multithreading now?

Comment: @user1650891: I am not going to answer a question here that has been asked on a different page. I'm only answering here what you have asked here. But I might take a look at your other question later on.

Comment: @user1650891: But I will say in reply to your comment above that the timer issue is likely due to your timer firing on a background thread. Because Windows Forms disallows cross-thread access to UI elements, in order to do anything with your UI, you need to get back on the UI thread first and execute your UI-related code there, e.g. using `someControlOrForm.Invoke(…)`.