# Open a form in new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a system tray application which has to perform some tasks like taking snapshot the screen, copying file, popping up a message etc. For Popping of a message, I am facing some difficulty as the popup message keeps other tasks pending until the message is closed. Please refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951542/how-to-automate-task-of-consuming-webservice) for more info.

Basically I want to open a new form from the existing form. I do not want to to close the new form to perform the task being kept pending on old form.

Can it be done using thread? How can it be done? I want to handle it using threading. I tried using form.show which is the simple answer to my question but since I am using timer the form.show() just keeps the form loading forever. Hence any reference for thread would be helpful.

Comment: Open the new form nonmodal and use a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @UweKeim can you please provide any links to refer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx      


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @codyG I know there's similar question, but the solution provided in [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550901/opening-a-different-form-inside-running-form-without-interrupting-execution-of-t) thread does not help me. The solution there is to user form.show but even after using form.show my issue is not resolved. Here I am talking about threads and not form.show().

Comment: @ETFovac thanks for the links but I am using winform.

Comment: You have to actually read and understand the answer in order to apply it. You can't just copy and paste the code. If you still can't figure it out, edit your question to explain the problems you're having.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multithreading to open a form and be able to acces old form while the new form is open. Just display the new form with `myform.Show()` instead of `myform.Showdialog()`

Comment: yes it used to works with myform.Show() unit I added a timer to it. refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951542/how-to-automate-task-of-consuming-webservice)

Comment: I think that when you open new form with Show it is already working in the new thread. I can explain how to open new form in the new thread, but i don't think it will make big difference. Can you explain what's the problem with timer when you are using show?

Comment: With timer, the form just seems to be loading always. As the timer is continuously incrementing and the app does not exit, the form just keeps on lading. I cannot even close the form and when i end the application form is closed.